# How to build a online Project Monitoring System

Tags: project-management, monitoring

I need to build a online project monitoring system for my project. Can anyone help me to identify the tools which I can use to build a simple online project monitoring system.

My system requires the following:
1. It should be user driven(multiuser logins)
2. Able to handle document uploads and downloads
3. If it can support spread sheet like document editing it will be good

Thanks,
Need your help.

Comment: Do you need to build one? There are plenty of project management systems out there that closely match in functionality. (e.g. sharepoint, jira/confluence, etc)

Comment: thanks, that's might help me, i want exactly such systems, do u have any more and if you can help to choose the easy and best one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is open source then you can use [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/)

Otherwise some paid solutions are

- Sharepoint - Group Collaborative
- Jira/Confluence - Source Control, Group Collaborative

Here are some [free project hosting](http://www.straw-dogs.co.uk/09/20/6-free-svn-project-hosting-services/) solutions,